# How to import Angular service from distributed module?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a distributable *(NPM using ng-packagr)* Angular service.  I have created the service and the module.  I am using

```
export class MyModule {
    static forRoot(configs: MyConfigs): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
        ngModule: MyModule,
        providers: [MyService, { provide: 'configs', useValue: configs }]
      };
    }
  }
```

So the user can configure the service in `app.module`.

```
import { MyModule } from 'themodule';

//...

imports: [
 MyModule.forRoot({/*configs*/});
```

**That all works just fine.**

*But I must be missing something.*

How does one import the service so they can reference the service for injection.

```
import { MyService } from 'themodule';

constructor(private myservice: MyService) { }
```

I know I am doing something stupid here. I mean the service is imported into `app.module` just fine.

**UPDATE:**

Well dear god help me!

All I had to do was add it to the exports in `public_api.d.ts`

I guess my head was in "***It has to be complicated!***" mode.

Unless someone has an alternative [proper angular centric style] answer, this was my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well dear god help me!

All I had to do was add it to the exports in `public_api.d.ts`

I guess my head was in "***It has to be complicated!***" mode.

*... not complicated.*